# How to estimate taps required for Parks-McClellan filters

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter

I have some code based on Jake Janovetz's Parks-McClellan (Remez) filter generating code. How can I estimate the number of taps required to build a lowpass filter given requirements for pass band ripple and stop band attenuation? I already know how to convert from these requirements back to the filter error deviation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using MATLAB, the function `firpmord` exists to help you with that. Like some other MATLAB functions, it doesn't link to any libraries or mex files, it's simply MATLAB code that runs. The only reason I mention it is that when you open this function (`open firpmord`), it has a subfunction `remlpord` that was written by (*ta-daaaaa*!) J. H. McClellan himself. It's using a matrix of hardcoded numbers and references *Rabiner & Gold, Theory and Appications of DSP, pp. 156-7*. The method therefore must be somewhat empirical, though I won't argue one way or the other. In any case, you can study this function (it's very short) and write your own based on it. I failed to find any specific papers that address the problem though, but perhaps there are books.

Comment: I don't have access to matlab at the moment, but I do have a copy of Rabiner and Gold.

Comment: After reading the book and playing around a bit, I find that for my problem set, simply using N = 1.9/transition_bandwidth + 2 gives very good results. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: That very much may be the case. If I find any reference with the actual method MATLAB uses in it, I will make sure to update my answer.